# Google app engine - Server response 503 code

Tags: google-app-engine

### It worked well last week. But started from this week, some instance response 503 failure. Tried to deploy it again, sometimes fixed the issue but after 1 day broken again with 503 failure. Don't know how to debug the issue. The code is the same and it worked before.

It is running in GAE standard.
Update the log after changed the log permission:

2018-07-09 09:53:09.000 CDT
Info: Limiting Java heap size to: 2563M
2018-07-09 09:53:09.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:09.670:INFO::main: Logging initialized @412ms
2018-07-09 09:53:11.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:11.111:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.5.v20151012
2018-07-09 09:53:11.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:11.204:INFO:oejs.AbstractNCSARequestLog:main: Opened /var/log/app_engine/request.2018_07_09.log
2018-07-09 09:53:13.000 CDT
Warning: caught exception when reading logging properties.
2018-07-09 09:53:13.000 CDT
java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF/logging.properties (No such file or directory)
2018-07-09 09:53:26.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:26.917:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
2018-07-09 09:53:27.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:27.338:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started c.g.a.v.j.VmRuntimeWebAppContext@fad74ee{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,AVAILABLE}
2018-07-09 09:53:27.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:27.388:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1697a57c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2018-07-09 09:53:27.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:53:27.392:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @18134ms
2018-07-09 09:54:55.000 CDT
Jul 09, 2018 2:54:55 PM com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext doScope
2018-07-09 09:54:55.000 CDT
WARNING: Response for request to '/_ah/start' was already committed (code=302). This might result in lost log messages.'
2018-07-09 09:54:55.472 CDT
GET
302
0 B
67 ms
curl/7.52.1
/_ah/start
2018-07-09 09:55:59.000 CDT
Jul 09, 2018 2:55:59 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.VmStopFilter doFilter
2018-07-09 09:55:59.000 CDT
INFO: Running shutdown hook
2018-07-09 09:55:59.000 CDT
Jul 09, 2018 2:55:59 PM com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmAppLogsWriter waitForCurrentFlush
2018-07-09 09:55:59.000 CDT
INFO: End of request or previous flush has not yet completed, blocking.
2018-07-09 09:56:02.000 CDT
Jul 09, 2018 2:56:02 PM com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate runSyncCall
2018-07-09 09:56:02.000 CDT
INFO: Error body: RPC Error: /StubbyService.Send to (unknown) : APP_ERROR(2)
2018-07-09 09:56:02.000 CDT
Jul 09, 2018 2:56:02 PM com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmAppLogsWriter waitForCurrentFlush
2018-07-09 09:56:02.000 CDT
WARNING: A log flush request failed. Log messages may have been lost!
2018-07-09 09:56:02.000 CDT
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RPCFailedException: The remote RPC to the application server failed for the call logservice.Flush(). at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmAppLogsWriter.waitForCurrentFlush(VmAppLogsWriter.java:226) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmAppLogsWriter.flushAndWait(VmAppLogsWriter.java:211) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyEnvironment.flushLogs(VmApiProxyEnvironment.java:508) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmRuntimeUtils.flushLogsAndAddHeader(VmRuntimeUtils.java:109) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext.doScope(VmRuntimeWebAppContext.java:323) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RPCFailedException: The remote RPC to the application server failed for the call logservice.Flush(). at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.runSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:175) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeApiCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:155) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.access$000(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:75) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:434) at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:410) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ... 1 more
2018-07-09 09:56:02.000 CDT
2018-07-09 09:56:02.213 CDT
GET
200
2 B
2.4 s
curl/7.52.1
/_ah/stop
2018-07-09 09:56:03.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:56:03.226:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-1: Stopped ServerConnector@6ef8e973{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2018-07-09 09:56:03.000 CDT
2018-07-09 14:56:03.258:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-1: Stopped c.g.a.v.j.VmRuntimeWebAppContext@fad74ee{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}

---

The permission changed:
triage@appspot.gserviceaccount.com  App Engine default service account
Editor
Logs Writer
Owner

---

The interesting thing is it worked well till last week.

---

503 error shows when I tried to access the website.
2018-07-11 11:16:26.296 CDT
GET
302
0 B
1 ms
Chrome 67
/
 144.188.128.2 - - [11/Jul/2018:11:16:26 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36" "jira-dot-triage-dash.appspot.com" ms=NaN cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=c5f3ef3880f528001e59cf18cd707937

2018-07-11 11:16:27.637 CDT
GET
503
0 B
7 ms
Chrome 67
/
144.188.128.2 - a2003 [11/Jul/2018:11:16:27 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36" "triage.appspot.com" ms=NaN cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.54 trace_id=1ce270202eb79067c9c6020089379b1b

Comment: If your app has low traffic, it may be that App Engine needs to spin up a new instance to serve the request, and this takes so long that the request is aborted.  Consider reducing the amount of work your app has to do to be ready for its first request.

Comment: The app has very low traffic. In fact, the only thing did during the initialization is read some datastore data. I can remove them to check. But I doubt it impacts. The instance was working very well.

Comment: I guess it maybe due to the error "INFO: Error body: RPC Error: /StubbyService.Send to (unknown) : APP_ERROR(2)".

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the [roles/logging.logWriter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#overview) role to your App Engine service account. It seems it can't call `logservice.Flush()` and it may be because of missing permissions.

Comment: Thanks LundinCast. I modified the permission. Looks like the RPC Error is gone. But the 503 issue is still there. "'" The new log:A  GET 302 0 B 62 ms curl/7.52.1 /_ah/start  GET 302 0 B 62 ms curl/7.52.1
A  GET 404 324 B 2 ms curl/7.52.1 /_ah/stop  GET 404 324 B 2 ms curl/7.52.1

Comment: Can you please edit the original question post to include the updated error messages in addition to the ones that you have originally posted so that it would be more informative? Also, are you using GAE standard or flexible?

Comment: Hi Philipp, I updated the new log. Looks like it is similar.

Comment: The information that you have provided does not have neither the 404 error mentioned here, nor the 503 error stated in the original title and description of the issue. Also, the RPC error did not seem to go away. Was the RPC error absent temporarily and now it is back? Are you not experiencing 404? And where do you see 503 because it is not in the logs.

Comment: Every time when I tried to access, it return 503 error. The reason I think it because ServerConnector:Thread-1: Stopped . The service is not started.  I will paste the 503 log above.

Comment: Looks like it would be better if you would open a ticket with support with this case since this would need a deeper investigation. If you do not have a paid support package or your trial period has expired, let me know.

Comment: Basically, if you cannot open a support ticket, raise a private issue in the Public Issue Tracker with your project number (do NOT mention your project ID please):
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164